# Need to convert Photoshop layers to InDesign layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, cs6, cs4

I'm using Photoshop CS6 to make a label and I need to convert all layers to InDesign CS4. I've never done this...is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

It can not be done.

There is no direct method for converting a Photoshop File to an InDesign file.

You can create a new InDesign document and *place* (link to) the Photoshop file. But other than that you must recreate the file in InDesign.

Answer (score 5):

I think this might be the easiest way:

1. Create an InDesign document the same size as your Photoshop Document.
2. Place the Photoshop Document on the page so it lines up perfectly.
3. If you have for example 3 layers in the Photoshop document, create 3 Layers in InDesign. Now copy the Object and paste in place `ctrl + shft + v` so that the object is repeated/placed on top, once for each InDesign layer.
4. Now select each object (hide the other InDesign layers to make it easy) and right-click the image object and select from the menu `Object` → `Object Layer Options`. Here you can turn off layers within the Photoshop document. You want to show only one Photoshop layer per InDesign layer, so in the bottom layer of InDesign, turn off all the Photoshop file layers except the bottom one. Repeat this for all corresponding layers.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this with CC is to export layers to files, under the export tab, make sure transparency is on and all artboards/layer backgrounds are transparent. I found for myself exporting to pngs works better than psds, as sometime the psds place without transparency in indesign.Then export, note this will take a while, then place the layers in indesign all at once and you will have the separate layers in indesign as required

Answer (score 1):

> You can create designs in Photoshop CS5 and then import the native PSD
>   files from Photoshop directly into InDesign. InDesign CS5 provides you
>   with additional control over the designs after an image is imported
>   into a layout.
>
> Using InDesign, you can import a layered Photoshop file, turn layers
>   on and off, or even layer comps to be placed. Follow these steps:
>
> - Have a layered Photoshop file ready to place.
> - Using InDesign, choose `File→Place`.
> - Browse to the location of a layered image file
> - Select the file you want to import
> - Select the Show Import Options check box, and then click Open.
>
> A dialog box appears.
>
> - Choose which Photoshop layers you want to use when placing a PSD file    into your InDesign layout.
> - Click the Layers tab and turn off and on the visibility of the layers    you want to change
>
> or
>
> - Select a saved layer comp from the Layer Comp drop-down list.
> - Click OK to close the Image Import Options dialog box.
>
> ### Transparency support and clipping paths
>
> Many Photoshop files
>   use transparency. The transparency in the PSD files is imported and
>   interpreted by InDesign. This feature is particularly useful when you
>   have an established background or want to have interesting text wrap
>   around an image you import from Photoshop.
>
> Basically, you can use the transparency as a clipping path in
>   InDesign. A clipping path resembles a hard-edged mask that hides parts
>   of an image, such as a background, that you don’t want visible around
>   a certain part of the image.
>
> You can use alpha channels, paths, and masks that you create in
>   Photoshop in InDesign. InDesign recognizes these parts of the PSD
>   file, so you can use them when you’re wrapping text around the image
>   or when you want to create a clipping path.
>
> Alternatively, you can also use these parts to remove a background
>   from the image. For example, if you have an image with one of these
>   assets, you can use the Detect Edges feature in InDesign to detect the
>   edges and wrap text around the image.
>
> Photoshop spot colors in InDesign If you’re using spot colors in an
>   image you import from Photoshop, those colors show up in the Swatches
>   panel in InDesign. There is a chance that a color from your spot
>   colors channel won’t be recognized. If that’s the case, the color is
>   shown as gray instead.
>
> You can use the swatches imported with the Photoshop file with other
>   parts of your file. Simply use the swatches as you would any other
>   swatch in InDesign. You can’t delete these swatches unless you remove
>   the Photoshop file that you imported into InDesign.

Source: http://www.dummies.com/DummiesArticle/Integrate-Photoshop-PSD-into-InDesign-Creative-Suite-5.id-286067.html

Comment: This is a straight-up word-identical copy'n'paste from a (presumably) copywritten work. Cool factor: -10

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this.  It's perfectly normal to link to other content sources for references.  In many cases, admins prefer you not direct link and paste the content into your answer, in case the link 404's later.  His answer helped me.